# How to control the access of AWS secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, secret-manager

Suppose I am an AWS Superuser who has all AWS permissions.

I have configured AWS glue including the connection to a database using username and password.

I have stored the username and password in AWS secret manager, the glue’s ETL job script will connect database using this information and then run the ETL job.

ETL Data engineers do not have super user permission. But they know how to write the details of the ETL job script. And the script needs to retrieve the secret info first, which means engineers can write code to print out the password… and we have a lot of Data engineers…

My question is: what is the right strategy to control the password access of the secret manager?

1) Shall we allow ETL data engineers to update script to glue and run it? then they can see the password, or

2) Shall we only allow them to write ETL script, but let superuser to update the script to glue after reviewing the code? or

3) Do we have a way to separate the ETL job script code and get_password code?

Note, I know How to use IAM, tags to control secret manager. But my question is different.

Comment: Hi, Hopefully following link will help you.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/

Comment: Thanks user3535130. It is helpful, although it does not answer my question.